# Why it doesnt work? Python, order, cycling

Tags: python, while-loop

I have problem. My code is following:

```
 algorythm--- solved
```

my file 'masiny.txt'

```
m1 dns mail 
m2 none dhcp 
m3 none firewall 
m4 firewall ftp 
m5 mail voice
```

first column is 'ID', second 'depends' and third 'provide'. Its about virtual machinech, which one provide such of servies, or depend on it.

My problem, hmm, when i run this my script, it frozen by starting machine 'm7'. Why? I think logic is good, but meybe mistake is in this two lines of code:

```
for j in running:  # get running services
    if j==dep[i] and i in notstarted:  # if important service is running and machnie is unopened
```

but why this loop is running three times, and then froze?
I am using python 3.3.3
please help, i am sitting with this all day

Thanks :)

error is following[image]

Comment: Please give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)—in particular, code that actually runs (which includes no `IndentationError`s where we have to guess what you meant and might guess wrong) and demonstrates the same problem you describe. When I guess at your indentation and run it, it prints "Starting m3", "Starting m2", "next phase", "Starting m4", "Starting m9". It's hard to tell you why it freezes at "starting machine 'm7'" when I see no such thing…

Comment: edited with picture :)

Comment: in fact what you are trying to achieve is simple **topological sorting**, which is more efficient way of doing so, and which would show you the problem (as topological sort would detect loop and inform you about it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't actually start all of the machines according to the rules. The first few can start:

```
none > dhcp, firewall
firewall > ftp
ftp > http
http > tele
```

At that point you can't do any more, but the following are still in `notstarted` so the code loops indefinitely:

```
m1 (mail, needs dns)
m5 (voice, needs mail)
m6 (chat, needs voice)
m7 (dns, needs chat)
```

These machines are in a loop `dns > chat > voice > mail > dns`, so can never be started.

Comment: thanks a lot.. I tried to find mistake in algorithmus, now its working, thanks for help :)